# PPAs for updated bash and zsh shells

Tags: bash, ppa, zsh

I would like to use newer versions of `bash` and `zsh`.

I've searched google for:

```
site:launchpad.net bash "ppa"
```

I've also searched at: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=bash

Doing the same for `zsh` also turned up nothing.

Based on the link in the first comment I tried:

```
dudette% sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bash
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~bash/ubuntu/ppa'.
The user named '~bash' does not have any PPA
dudette% sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zsh 
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~zsh/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~zsh' user or team does not exist.
```

How do I find the PPAs for these two shells? **I only have ssh access.**

---

**Close queue reviewers:**  I looked through the supposed duplicate. This question is about finding the PPA, not installing software. Also, I cant run Y-PPA Manager as suggested in the comment - I only have ssh access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu) (read about [Y-PPA-Manager](https://askubuntu.com/a/1000768/66509)).

Comment: I guess there is no PPA providing these two package, you have to compile it yourself.

Comment: `bash` is essential on Ubuntu systems, why exactly do you need a newer version?

Comment: @dessert to get the newer features of this essential package. :)

Comment: I’d compile the software myself: Download e.g. [bash-bash-5.0-testing.tar.gz](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/snapshot/bash-bash-5.0-testing.tar.gz) and compile following the instructions in `INSTALL`. You should never *replace* the system’s `bash` though, just put the compiled binary anywhere outside `PATH` and run it from there.